# How to get nodejs on client-side on cordova?

Tags: node.js, api, cordova, client

I am making a app with cordova. I want the coinmarketcap stats in it. I am using nodejs and it is working fine when I execute it in my command line. However I want to use it in my cordova application. This is the link to the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-coinmarketcap

When I try to run it in a browser I get the error message require not defined. I believe that error comes because nodesj is a server-side and browser is a client side ? Am I correct ?

My code

```
var CoinMarketCap = require("node-coinmarketcap");
var coinmarketcap = new CoinMarketCap();

coinmarketcap.multi(coins => {

  console.log(coins.getTop(10)); // Prints information about top 10 cryptocurrencies
});
```

I expect that I can run my code in my browser or cordova application.

Comment: require is not supported on webview

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Node.js is a JavaScript run-time environment that executes JavaScript code outside of a browser. You have to find some client-side JS code or execute your node code on your server and send result to your Cordova app.